# how to handle errors in quasar boot files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, quasar-framework

In our quasar application we have a few boot files, some of them can run into an exception which should block the application from starting normally, instead an error should be displayed.

Is there some best-practice for such a case? I didn't find much in the documentation.

My approach was the following, if an error occurs forward/redirect to an error page and display the error.

I need to somehow pass the error to the error-page:

- passing the message as GET parameter would be a bad idea => XSS
- I also cannot pass an error ID/Key because the error may come from a server with various messages
- Storing the error in a vuex store does not work because the store is reset after `reject()` is called.

So I was thinking maybe there is a better way of doing handling errors in boot files?
Stop current booting and goto error-page...

Here is an reduced example which will end in the */error* page but with the `store.error` empty, `reject()` will reboot the application reset the `store`.

```
export default ({ app, store, urlPath }) => {
  // required to prevent invinite loop, the reject(url) will reboot application
  if (urlPath.indexOf("error") !== -1) {
    // TODO be more specific then indexOf("error")
    return;
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doSomeServerCommunication()
      .then((result) => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        store.commit("appStore/updateError", e);
        reject({ url: window.location.origin + "/app/error" });
        return;
      });
  });
};
```